# Interrupting and restarting a loop of setTimeouts

Tags: javascript

I am trying to play audio files with timed text appearing at the same time. When the 'Play' button is pushed, a random audio file is chosen and it's subtitles and timing are loaded. Then a loop of setTimeouts is used to replace the existing text with the appropriate text at the right time.

This seems to work fine, but the issue is that I need to be able to interrupt the audio and have the subtitles stop and be able to work again when I press 'Play'.

Here's a minimal 'working' version of my code:

```
var playing = false;
var timeout;

var allSubs = [
    "A1 | A2 | A3",
    "B1 | B2 | B3 | B4",
    "C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5",
]

var allTimings = [
    "0 | 2 | 4",
    "0 | 1 | 2 | 3",
    "0 | 0.5 | 1 | 1.5 | 2",
]

function playAudio() {
    playing = true;
    $('#media-control').text('Stop');

    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3));

    var subtitleStr = allSubs[index];
    var timingStr = allTimings[index];

    subtitleArr = subtitleStr.split(' | ');
    timingArr = timingStr.split(' | ').map(Number);

    for (i = 0; i < subtitleArr.length; i++) {
        timeout = setTimeout((function(i) {
            return function() {
                $('#subtitle-text').text(subtitleArr[i]);
            }
        })(i), timingArr[i] * 1000);
    }
}

function stopAudio() {
    playing = false;
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    $('#media-control').text('Play');
    $('#subtitle-text').text('');
}

function toggleMedia(e) {
    if (!playing) {
        playAudio();
    } else {
        stopAudio();
    }
}

$('#media-control').bind('click', toggleMedia);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eshapiro42/bjme90yt/12/

If you press 'Play'/'Stop' enough times in quick succession, eventually the subtitles stop appearing in the correct order and at the correct times.

Can someone please recommend either a better way of creating timed text or a way of interrupting the setTimeout loop which actually works deterministically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your issue is in the playAudio function. You are iterating over all of the subtitles at once, and setting timeouts for each one. You are overriding the previous timeout's ID when you set the next one. So the only timeout truly being canceled when you hit pause is the last one.

What you need to do is store an array of these timeout IDs. Push to the array when you make a new timeout. When you press pause, clear all timeouts from that array.

```
var allTimeouts = [];
...
allTimeouts.push(timeout); // On setting the timeouts
...
for(int i = 0; i < allTimeouts.length; i++){ // On clearing the timeouts 
    clearTimeout(allTimesouts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed :D